# Python XML ElementTree Removing All Elements

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm writing a script that is supposed to remove parent elements from the XML file if the child element matches an element in a CSV file. The loops and if statements are working correctly, however when I add the remove, it just deletes everything out of the table regardless of if it matches or not. I can't seem to figure out why it is doing this.

```
cs = open('skus.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(cs)


tree = et.parse('christmas-dog-price.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
xmlns = {'pricebook': '{http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/pricebook/2006-10-31}'}
price_table = root.find('.//{pricebook}price-table'.format(**xmlns))
product_id = [price_table.get('product-id') for price_table in root]
for sku in reader:
    for product in product_id:
        for price_table in root:
            if sku[0] != product:
                continue
            if sku[0] == product:
                root.remove(price_table)
            tree.write('please-work.xml')
```

Comment: shouldn't this `tree.write('please-work.xml')` be outside the loops?

Comment: please share the xml structure and variable initialization for `product` and `root` and `tree`

Comment: @VikashSingh  example xml structure (without headers):                                                                                 <price-table product-id="tr-33373">
        <amount quantity="1">11.99</amount>
      </price-table>

Comment: @VikashSingh so each product has a price table. i'm trying to set it up so that if the product-id is equal to a product id in a csv document, it deletes that specific price table. if it is not equal, it is left alone.

Comment: @VikashSingh in this scenario, tree.write('please-work.xml') can be placed outside the loop for speed's sake.

Comment: Thanks for all this info but more code is needed. initialisation of reader, product_id and root..

Comment: what's `sku`? If any `sku[0]` is equal to any `product`, everything is removed from `root`.

Comment: @VikashSingh (how do you format code in comments?)

Comment: @KevinPasquarella edit the question, update details there. More details is better..

Comment: @VikashSingh ok, I've edited it to include everything in the script

Comment: @Daniel I understand where you are coming from, however if put print statements under the if statements, everything prints as it should. so in theory if it's finding the equal product id and printing it, shouldn't the root.remove() work as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you get all product ids form xml and compare them with each id in your csv-file. If any matches, you remove every element from root.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
for sku in reader:
    for product in product_id:
        if sku[0] == product:
            for price_table in root:
                root.remove(price_table)
tree.write('please-work.xml')
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
if any(sku[0] in product_id for sku in reader):
    for price_table in root:
        root.remove(price_table)
tree.write('please-work.xml')
```

You should compare only the current product-id which each id of the csv-file:

```
with open('skus.csv', 'rb') as cs:
    reader = csv.reader(cs)
    product_ids = [sku[0] for sku in reader]

tree = et.parse('christmas-dog-price.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
xmlns = {'pricebook': '{http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/pricebook/2006-10-31}'}
price_table = root.find('.//{pricebook}price-table'.format(**xmlns))
to_be_removed = [element for element in price_table if price_table.get('product-id') in product_ids]
for element in to_be_removed:
    root.remove(element)
```